# Web.py returns invalid JSON to jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, json, firefox, web.py

In my web.py application I have this class

```
class region_info(object):
    def GET(self,region=''):
        rtnDict = {
            'regionExists': False,
            'regionInfo': {
                'name': 'Unknown Region',
                'sum_information': 'No Summary Information Available'
            }

        }

        if region and region != 'world':
            rtnDict['regionExists'] = True
            rtnDict['regionInfo']['name'] = 'The region Name'
            rtnDict['regionInfo']['sum_information'] = """The region's summary information goes here and can be long
            and multilined"""

        web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return json.dumps(rtnDict)
```

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function loadRegionInfo(code)
{
    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/map/regioninfo/"+code,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(result)
            {
                if (result.regionExists == true )
                {
                    $("#country-info-header").text(result.name);
                    $("#country-info-summary").html(result.sum_information);
                }

            }
    });
}
```

In FireBug, I get data that looks like this:

`{"regionExists": true, "regionInfo": {"sum_information": "The region's summary information goes here and can be long\n            and multilined", "name": "The region Name"}}`

[JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) says this is valid JSON

Firefox, however, tells me that it is "not well-formed". Because of this error, I assume, the success function in my jQuery.ajax call is falling because my DIVs are not updating as expected. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this is actually the case, because Chrome doesn't report the same error.

Is there actually anything wrong with my JSON response?

If it is valid, what is my error on why my DIVs don't properly update?

[image: Firefox Error Message]

Comment: It's valid. Make sure there are no extra lines or spaces before the json.

Comment: @KevinB, there are no extra lines or spaces before what I posted in the response. Viewing the source of the response in Firefox shows the first character is at Line 1, Col 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed at debugging my code. I am returning a JSON string that has this format

```
'regionExists': false,
'regionInfo': {
    'country': "A country",
    'sum_information': "Summary information"
}
```

The DIVs weren't updating because I was attempting to get data from `result.country` not `result.regionInfo['country']`.

The JavaScript error is actually an XML error according to Firebug, not a JSON error.